# Getting selection of wx.treectrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

tree.GetSelection() gives the actual tree id object.

I would like to get a int of the selection just like a listbox.GetSelection() would return.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TreeItemId` object should have a `GetID` method which will return its id in the tree

### Edit

the tree control has a built in feature to store additional information on the tree item.

```
item= self.tree.GetSelection()
self.tree.SetPyData(item,{"Source":"C:\hi.png","Opacity":1})
print self.tree.GetPyData(item)
```

Comment: You're right, I was looking at the [wxwidgets api](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_tree_item_id.html) rather than the wxpython one. It appears that the method doesn't exist under wxPython. What's the reason you need the int of the item? If you explain what it is you want to do I'm sure there's a way to do it without knowing the id of the item

Comment: I am making an image editor. So each element on the tree will be an image. I would like to store some data in a dictionary based on the index of the element.  So it would be like; {0:{"Source":"C:\hi.png","Opacity":1}}

Comment: @user1513192 Hey check my edit- think that should solve your problem :)